# Получение местоположения пользователя

Tags: android, gps, карты

При запуске приложения требуется получить местоположение пользователя на карте. Погуглив и посмотрев в книге, единственное, что я нашел — это использовать слушатель смены расстояния:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //Получаю местоположение и отписываюсь
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            ...
        }
   ...
}
```

Такой способ не всегда работает. Иногда приложение ждет 10 секунд-2 минуты, прежде чем слушатель сработает. Иногда просто не срабатывает (если телефон не двигается).

---

Есть какая-то 100% работающая альтернатива запросить текущее расстояние (при условия нормальной работы GPS), а не ждать ответа в слушатель изменения?

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что такое решение реально существует. Всегда будут какие-то **но**. Возможно, если вам всего однажды нужно местоположение, то надо не слушатель изменения оного юзать, а [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) у которого запрашивать последнее известное местоположение

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, такое может не подойти. Если я получу не ту точку, машина поедет не туда. На случай не нахождения места - попрошу ввести его вручную.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему вы запрашиваете в провайдере именно GPS_PROVIDER? GPS долго прогревается при холодном старте и из-за этого возникают задержки в 20-120 секунд. Если использовать координаты сети/Wi-Fi, то локацию можно получить почти моментально.

Попробуйте [reactive-location](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation), там есть пример получения локации с таймаутом, получится хороший флоу для Вашего случая:

```
LocationRequest req = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setExpirationDuration(5000)
            .setInterval(1000);

    Observable<Location> goodEnoughQuicklyOrNothingObservable = new ReactiveLocationProvider(getContext())
            .getUpdatedLocation(req)
            .filter(location -> location.getAccuracy() < 50) // с точностью до 50 метров
            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just(null), AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .first()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    Subscription subscription = goodEnoughQuicklyOrNothingObservable
            .subscribe(location -> {
                        if (location == null) {
                            // не удалось получить координаты,
                            // требуется ввод вручную
                        } else {
                            // получили координаты
                        }
                    }, Timber::e);
```

Comment: Попробую завтра, сегодня уже сложил ноутбук. Но сразу вопрос: что, если увеличить точность до 5-10 метром, это повлияет на скорость?

Comment: @RostislavDugin, проверил у себя в режиме GPS "по всем координатам GPS/Wi-Fi/LTE", точность сначала была ~30 метров, затем в течение секунд 30 падала до ~10-15 и оставалась на таком уровне

Comment: В ближайшее время могу не успеть попробовать Ваш вариант. Если не успею, приму Ваш ответ и отдам награду :).

Comment: У меня с точностью (фильтром) менее 50-ти метров не находит совсем, а с точностью `<= 50` — практически сразу.

Answer (score 5):

Спустя неделю поисков и вопроса на enSO и ruSO, я пришел к варанту, что альтернатив - нет.

Местоположение можно определить только с помощью `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates` и получить последнее местоположение, которое запомнил телефон методом [FocusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi).

---

Как альтернативу, можно предложить пользователю выбрать местоположение через маркер или ввести вручную.

В этом помогут [автоввод местоположения](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) и [определение местоположения через координаты.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=ru#ReverseGeocoding)

Answer (score 0):

В качестве альтернатив можно предложить разве что ручной ввод местоположения. Еще было бы хорошо требовать от пользователя включения `Wi-Fi`, для более точного позиционирования. Да и получение координат через `Wi-Fi`/`A-GPS` будет работать гораздо быстрее - моментально даже. Ведь в отличии от GPS не тратиться время на поиск спутников.

Comment: Я это и написал в ответе. Зачем повторять?

Comment: @RostislavDugin вообще-то у меня другой ответ. Не понимаю, за что минусуете. МОжет я и подтвердил ваше мнения в первом предложении, но за что минусуете?

Comment: За то что Вы банально скопировали мой ответ, изменив три предложения, расчитывая на какой-то плюс в репутацию.

Comment: @AndreyYanov первая версия вашего ответа содержала фрагмент, идентичный фрагменту ответа Rostislav. Больше такой текст нигде не гуглится, так что непохоже, чтобы вы оба скопировали из одного места. Поэтому похоже, что вы просто скопировали часть ответа, не указав источник. Не нужно так делать, пользы никакой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ответ исправил, ненужно дизлайкать